# How do I incorporate jScrollPane into a Wordpress PHP header file?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

Can anyone give me a hand? This is for a charity event and coding clearly isn't my day job.  The site is www.gingertown.org/wp

I don't understand where to put this line:

```
$(function() {
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```

I also have a feeling I'm not calling the js correctly. From [digging into wordpress](http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way)

I modified my file to look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<title><?php wp_title('&#124;', true, 'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> RSS Feed" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</code></pre>

    <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
    <?php wp_enqueue_script( 'sfhover', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/sfhover.js' ); ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>

    <!-- the mousewheel plugin - optional to provide mousewheel support -->
    <script type="text/javascript" 
 src="script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

    <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" 
 src="script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>



    </head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put it after the jscrollpane plugin is included, here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($) {         //since your site is calling jQuery.noConflict()
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
  });
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had it there before, but it doesn't seem to do anything. The specific page that it should show on is http://gingertown.org/wp/?cat=142

Comment: @Jason - Change `$(function() {` to `jQuery(function($) {` to fix the current error, can you update the live site with that?

Comment: I changed the live site. It still doesn't pick up anything other than the default scrollbar.

Comment: @Jason - I'm getting a 404 for your script: http://gingertown.org/wp/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js So you're getting an error when trying to call `.jScrollPane()`.

Comment: $(".scroll-pane").jScrollPane is not a function
[Break on this error] $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows: true});

Comment: If it is unable to call, the problem would still be in the header. Correct?

Comment: @Jason -  Yes...that's because the plugin isn't included the URL I linked in the previous comment isn't valid, none of your `/script` files are actually there, you need to update those links to point to wherever your JavaScript actually is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you lost me. I have them in /script/*.js How is the link not pointing to them?

Comment: @Jason - The files aren't at that location, `script/` means  `http://gingertown.org/wp/script/` and the files aren't in there :)

Comment: OH! >>insert lightbulb on!<< My head was still in CSS links. That makes sense. I updated the location to point to the scripts folder in my theme. It's still giving the same console error about it not being a function.

Comment: @Jason - Still getting a 404: http://gingertown.org/public_html/wp/wp-content/themes/gingertown001/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js In Firefox view source, and you can click on he `.js` to get the same errors...so the script still aren't quite in the right place.

Comment: Okay. Hardcoded the links and they seem to be working now. Thanks for the patience with this! JS content is being generated on the page so I think I just have to sift through the css and/or div tags to make the scrollbar appear.